# Access VBA: New tables created in a loop causing error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm grabbing field row from one table and creating a new table for each row. The new tables will have names equal to the row they correspond to.

Here is my code:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function createTables()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "Select SKUS from SKUS"
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    Set fld = rst.Fields("SKUS")

    'MsgBox fld.Value

    rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(fld.Value)

        Set fld = tdf.CreateField("SKUS", dbText, 30)
        tdf.Fields.Append fld

        Set fld = tdf.CreateField("Count", dbInteger)
        tdf.Fields.Append fld

        db.TableDefs.Append tdf

        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

End Function
```

The problem is that after the first iteration of the code (the first table is created), it gives me an error "Invalid operation" pointing to the line

```
...
Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(fld.Value)
...
```

Why do you think this is? I have a feeling its because I need to re set fld or rst, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help me out with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to this?  This is a violation of data normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you're reading any new tuples from `rst`, thus the `CreateTableDef` will be called with the same value repeatedly. Try changing this:

```
[...]
Set fld = rst.Fields("SKUS")
rst.MoveFirst
Do While Not rst.EOF
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(fld.Value)
[...]
```

Into this:

```
[...]
rst.MoveFirst
Do While Not rst.EOF
    Set fld = rst.Fields("SKUS")
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(fld.Value)
[...]
```

...if your intention is to create one table based on every tuple in the SKUS table.

Comment: oh my god you are jesus that worked perfectly! ive been struggling with this for the past couple hours at work! Thank you!